# Why doesn't `httpd2 -S` catch SSL certificate issues whereas `systemctl restart apache2.service` does?

Tags: apache-2.4

I wonder why `rcapache2` (which redirects to `systemctl restart apache2.service`) fails with this error, but `httpd2 -S` doesn't complain at all:

```
Jun 28 14:37:50 revue start_apache2[4037]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl.crt/pluimers.com.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

I know the certificate should be there (it will in a minute), but I always presumed `httpd2 -S` would perform the same checks as `systemctl restart apache2.service` would do.

Apparently it doesn't.

SSL is enabled:

```
# grep APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS /etc/sysconfig/apache2
#   5. To finally enable ssl support, you need to add 'SSL' to APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS 
APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS="SSL"
```

My configuration is based on the [apache2-vhost-ssl.template](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/Apache/apache2/apache2-vhost-ssl.template). The template has the below condition. I think the cause is that the condition *is* satisfied by `apache2.service`, but *not* by `httpd2`:

```
<IfDefine SSL>
<IfDefine !NOSSL>
```

Is that indeed the cause? If so: why? If not: what is the cause?
How can I work around it using `httpd2 -S`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround (as `apache2ctl configtest` didn't work on my system):

```
httpd2 -D SSL -S
```

It will define the SSL switch which is in the `APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS` of `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`.

One day, I'll write a script that dissects the `APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS` value into multiple `-D` parameters.

Note so self: right now the prefork is started with these parameters `-f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -D SSL -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND`.

Answer (score 3):

Running `service` is going to invoke the full init script for apache2 which will be stored in `/etc/init.d/apache2`.  That script has lots of checks, including checking whether it is already running, that are unlikely to be included in the apache `httpd` itself.  You should get in the habit of using the `service` commands to stop and start things.  This works across most modern Linuxes.

If you want to just check your configuration without starting or stopping anything then you can do `apache2ctl configtest` which if all is well will report:

```
Syntax OK
```

Comment: I was hoping that `httpd2 -S` would perform all checks which the service start does, so you can spot configuration issues early. Is there any workaround to have `httpd2 -S` run a more complete init script before performing checks?

Comment: It looks like you can get close to the same thing from `apache2ctl configtest`.